# Display a custom Woocommerce product input field in the YITH Request a Quote table

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, plugins

So the previous developer created a custom plugin that adds an input field in the Woocommerce product editor in the wordpress dashboard. The value is being stored as the variable $unit inside of a class, as seen here:

```
<?php
/*******************************************************************************
 Display Custom Units Next to Quantity fields in Woocommerce 
*******************************************************************************/

/* 
  This is built based on 
  https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/adding-custom-fields-to-simple-products-with-woocommerce--cms-27904
*/

// Call classes dependent on front or backside
if ( is_admin() ) {
    
    $admin = new mg_custom_qty_units( 'mg_custom_unit' );
    $admin->init();
    
} else {
    
    $plugin = new mg_display_custom_unit( 'mg_custom_unit' );
    $plugin->init();
    
}

// Adding a custom meta field for the quantity units
class mg_custom_qty_units {

    /**
     * Maintains a value to the text field ID for serialization.
     *
     * @access private
     * @var    string
     */
    private $textfield_id;

    /**
     * Initializes the class and the instance variables.
     */
    public function __construct( $id ) {
        $this->textfield_id = $id;
    }

    /**
     * Initializes the hooks for adding the text field and saving the values.
     */
    public function init() {

        add_action('woocommerce_product_options_general_product_data', array( $this, 'mg_product_unit_options' ) );

        add_action( 'woocommerce_process_product_meta', array( $this, 'mg_add_qty_unit_save' ) );
    }

    /**
     * Initializes and renders the contents of the text field in the General Tab
     */
    public function mg_product_unit_options() {

        $description = sanitize_text_field(
            'Enter units product is sold in (i.e. pack, carton, etc)'
        );

        $placeholder = sanitize_text_field(
            ''
        );

        $args = array(
            'id'            => $this->textfield_id,
            'label'         => sanitize_text_field( 'Custom Quantity Units' ),
            'placeholder'   => $placeholder,
            'desc_tip'      => true,
            'description'   => $description,
        );
        woocommerce_wp_text_input( $args );
    }

    /**
     * Saves a sanitized version of the VHX Package ID values provided by the user.
     *
     * @param int $post_id The ID of the current post to which the IDs are associated.
     */
    public function mg_add_qty_unit_save( $post_id ) {

        if ( ! ( isset( $_POST['woocommerce_meta_nonce'], $_POST[ $this->textfield_id ] ) || wp_verify_nonce( sanitize_key( $_POST['woocommerce_meta_nonce'] ), 'woocommerce_save_data' ) ) ) { // Input var okay.
            return false;
        }

        $mg_custom_qty_unit = sanitize_text_field(
            wp_unslash( $_POST[ $this->textfield_id ] ) // Input var okay.
        );

        update_post_meta(
            $post_id,
            $this->textfield_id,
            esc_attr( $mg_custom_qty_unit )
        );
    }
}

class mg_display_custom_unit {

    /**
     * Maintains a value to the text field ID for serialization.
     *
     * @access private
     * @var    string
     */
    private $textfield_id;

    /**
     * Initializes the class and the instance variables.
     */
    public function __construct( $id ) {
        $this->textfield_id = $id;
    }

    /**
     * Registers hooks for displaying data on the front-end of the site.
     */
    public function init() {
        add_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_quantity', array( $this, 'mg_after_add_to_cart_quantity' ) );
    }
    
    /**
     * Retrieves the metadata and echos after the quantity field
     */
    public function mg_after_add_to_cart_quantity() {

        $unit = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), $this->textfield_id, true );
        if ( empty( $unit ) ) {
            echo '<div class="mg-qty-units empty"></div>';
        } else {
            echo '<div class="mg-qty-units">' . esc_html( $unit ) . '</div>';
        }

    }
}
```

The site also uses the YITH Request a Quote plugin that displays a table of all the selected products and provides the option to send a quote request, as seen here:

```
<?php
/**
 * This file belongs to the YIT Plugin Framework.
 *
 * @package YITH Woocommerce Request A Quote
 * This source file is subject to the GNU GENERAL PUBLIC LICENSE (GPL 3.0)
 * that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE.txt.
 * It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
 * http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-3.0.txt
 */

/**
 * Table view to Request A Quote
 *
 * @since   1.0.0
 * @author  YITH
 *
 * @package YITH Woocommerce Request A Quote
 * @version 3.0.0
 * @var  array $raq_content
 * @var string $show_thumbnail
 * @var string $show_sku
 * @var string $show_single_price
 * @var string $show_line_total
 * @var string $show_quantity
 * @var string $show_totals
 * @var string $shop_url
 * @var string $label_return_to_shop
 * @var string $shop_url_after_sent_email
 * @var string $label_return_to_shop_after_sent_email
 * @var string $show_back_to_shop
 * @var string $tax_display_list
 * @var string $show_unit
 */

$colspan = 4;

$colspan = $show_line_total ? $colspan : $colspan - 1;
$colspan = $show_thumbnail ? $colspan : $colspan - 1;
$colspan = $show_single_price ? $colspan : $colspan - 1;

$mobile_colspan = $colspan;
$mobile_colspan = $show_line_total ? $mobile_colspan - 1 : $mobile_colspan;
$mobile_colspan = $show_single_price ? $mobile_colspan - 1 : $mobile_colspan;


$responsive_class = apply_filters( 'ywraq_responsive_table_class', 'ywraq_responsive' ); // old class shop_table_responsive.
$total_tax        = 0;
?>
<div class="ywraq-before-form">
    <?php
    $quote_id = isset( $_GET['quote_id'] ) ? sanitize_text_field( wp_unslash( $_GET['quote_id'] ) ) : false; //phpcs:ignore
    if ( $quote_id && wc_get_order( $quote_id ) ) :
        $shortcode = '[yith_ywraq_single_view_quote order_id="' . $quote_id . '"]';
        echo wp_kses_post( is_callable( 'apply_shortcodes' ) ? apply_shortcodes( $shortcode ) : do_shortcode( $shortcode ) );
        echo '</div>';

    elseif ( count( $raq_content ) === 0 ) :
        if ( empty( $notices ) || 0 === $notices ) {
            echo wp_kses_post( ywraq_get_list_empty_message() );
        } else {
            ?>
            <a class="button "
               href="<?php echo esc_url( $shop_url_after_sent_email ); ?>"><?php echo esc_html( $label_return_to_shop_after_sent_email ); ?></a>
            <?php
        }
        echo '</div>';
    else :
        ?>

        <?php if ( $show_back_to_shop ) : ?>
        <a class="button return_to_shop_url"
           href="<?php echo esc_url( $shop_url ); ?>"><?php echo esc_html( $label_return_to_shop ); ?></a>
    <?php endif; ?>


        <?php

        if ( count( $raq_content ) !== 0 ) :
            echo '</div>';
            ?>

            <form id="yith-ywraq-form" name="yith-ywraq-form" method="post">

                <?php do_action( 'ywraq_before_list_table' ); ?>

                <table class="shop_table cart  <?php echo esc_attr( $responsive_class ); ?>" id="yith-ywrq-table-list">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="product-remove"></th>
                        <th class="product-name"
                            colspan="<?php echo $show_thumbnail ? '2' : '1'; ?>"><?php esc_html_e( 'Product', 'yith-woocommerce-request-a-quote' ); ?></th>
                        <?php if ( $show_single_price ) : ?>
                            <th class="product-price"><?php esc_html_e( 'Price', 'yith-woocommerce-request-a-quote' ); ?></th>
                        <?php endif ?>
                        <?php if ( $show_quantity ) : ?>
                            <th class="product-quantity"><?php esc_html_e( 'Quantity', 'yith-woocommerce-request-a-quote' ); ?></th>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        <?php if ( $show_line_total ) : ?>
                            <th class="product-subtotal"><?php esc_html_e( 'Subtotal', 'yith-woocommerce-request-a-quote' ); ?></th>
                        <?php endif ?>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <?php
                    $total        = 0;
                    $total_exc    = 0;
                    $total_inc    = 0;
                    foreach ( $raq_content as $key => $raq ) :
                        $product_id = ( ! empty( $raq['variation_id'] ) && $raq['variation_id'] > 0 ) ? $raq['variation_id'] : $raq['product_id'];
                        $_product = wc_get_product( $product_id );

                        if ( ! $_product ) {
                            continue;
                        }

                        // Wishlist integration.
                        if ( class_exists( 'YITH_WCWL' ) && empty( $raq['variation_id'] ) ) {

                            $variation  = wc_get_product( $raq['product_id'] );
                            $attributes = $variation->get_attributes();
                            $raq_data   = array();

                            if ( ! empty( $attributes ) ) {
                                foreach ( $attributes as $name => $value ) {
                                    $raq_data[ 'attribute_' . $name ] = $value;
                                }
                            }

                            $raq['variation_id'] = $raq['product_id'];
                            $raq['variations']   = $raq_data;
                        }

                        $show_price = true;
                        do_action( 'ywraq_quote_adjust_price', $raq, $_product );
                        $price = ( 'incl' === $tax_display_list ) ? wc_get_price_including_tax( $_product, array( 'qty' => 1 ) ) : wc_get_price_excluding_tax( $_product, array( 'qty' => 1 ) );
                        if ( $price ) {
                            $price_with_tax    = wc_get_price_including_tax( $_product, array( 'qty' => 1 ) );
                            $price_without_tax = wc_get_price_excluding_tax( $_product, array( 'qty' => 1 ) );
                            $price             = isset( WC()->cart ) ? apply_filters( 'yith_ywraq_product_price_html', WC()->cart->get_product_subtotal( $_product, 1 ), $_product, $raq ) : $_product->get_price();
                        } else {
                            $price = wc_price( 0 );
                        }

                        do_action( 'ywraq_before_request_quote_view_item', $raq_content, $key );

                        if ( ! empty( $raq['yith_wapo_individual_item'] ) && 1 === $raq['yith_wapo_individual_item'] && ! empty( $raq['yith_wapo_parent_key'] ) ) :
                            ?>
                            <tr class="<?php echo esc_attr( apply_filters( 'yith_ywraq_item_class', 'cart_item', $raq_content, $key ) ); ?>"
                                data-wapo_parent_key="<?php echo esc_attr( $raq['yith_wapo_parent_key'] ); ?>" <?php echo esc_attr( apply_filters( 'yith_ywraq_item_attributes', '', $raq_content, $key ) ); ?>>

                                <td class="product-remove"></td>
                                <?php if ( $show_thumbnail ) : ?>
                                    <td class="product-thumbnail"></td>
                                <?php endif; ?>

                                <td class="product-name"
                                    data-title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Product', 'yith-woocommerce-request-a-quote' ); ?>">
                                    <?php
                                    // Meta data.
                                    $item_data = array();

                                    foreach ( $raq['yith_wapo_options'] as $individual_item ) {
                                        $individual_wapo_item_price = '';
                                        if ( $show_price && $individual_item['price'] > 0 && 'yes' === get_option( 'ywraq_hide_price' ) ) {
                                            $individual_wapo_item_price = ' ( +' . wp_strip_all_tags( wc_price( $individual_item['price'] ) ) . ' ) ';
                                        }

                                        if ( class_exists( 'YITH_WAPO_WPML' ) ) {
                                            $key = YITH_WAPO_WPML::string_translate( $individual_item['name'] );
                                            if ( strpos( $individual_item['value'], 'Attached file' ) ) {
                                                $array = new SimpleXMLElement( $individual_item['value'] );
                                                $link  = $array['href']; //phpcs:ignore
                                                $value = '<a href="' . esc_url( $link ) . '" target="_blank">' . esc_html_x( 'Attached file', 'Integration: product add-ons attachment', 'yith-woocommerce-request-a-quote' ) . '</a>';
                                            } else {
                                                $value = YITH_WAPO_WPML::string_translate( $individual_item['value'] );
                                            }
                                        } else {
                                            $key   = $individual_item['name'];
                                            $value = $individual_item['value'];
                                        }

                                        $item_data[] = array(
                                            'key'   => $key . $individual_wapo_item_price,
                                            'value' => urldecode( $value ),
                                        );
                                    }

                                    // Output flat or in list format.
                                    if ( count( $item_data ) > 0 ) {
                                        echo '<ul style="margin-left: 10px;">';
                                        foreach ( $item_data as $data ) {
                                            echo '<li><strong>' . esc_html( $data['key'] ) . '</strong>: ' . wp_kses_post( $data['value'] ) . '</li><br>';
                                        }
                                        echo '</ul>';
                                    }
                                    ?>
                                    <?php if ( $show_line_total || $show_single_price ) : ?>
                                        <span
                                            class="mobile-price"><?php echo wp_kses_post( $show_single_price ? $price : $subtotal ); ?></span>
                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                </td>
                                <?php if ( $show_single_price ) : ?>
                                    <td class="product-price"
                                        data-title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Price', 'yith-woocommerce-request-a-quote' ); ?>">
                                        <?php
                                        echo wp_kses_post( apply_filters( 'yith_ywraq_hide_price_template', $price, $product_id, $raq ) );
                                        ?>
                                    </td>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                                <?php if ( $show_quantity ) : ?>
                                    <td class="product-quantity"
                                        data-title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Quantity', 'yith-woocommerce-request-a-quote' ); ?>">
                                        <?php echo esc_html( $raq['quantity'] ); ?>
                                    </td>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                                <?php if ( $show_line_total ) : ?>
                                    <td class="product-subtotal"
                                        data-title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Subtotal', 'yith-woocommerce-request-a-quote' ); ?>">
                                        <?php
                                        echo wp_kses_post( apply_filters( 'yith_ywraq_hide_price_template', $subtotal, $product_id, $raq ) );
                                        ?>
                                    </td>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                            </tr>
                        <?php

                        else :
                            $price = ( 'incl' === $tax_display_list ) ? wc_get_price_including_tax( $_product, array( 'qty' => $raq['quantity'] ) ) : wc_get_price_excluding_tax( $_product, array( 'qty' => $raq['quantity'] ) );

                            if ( $price ) {
                                if ( $_product->is_type( 'yith-composite' ) && isset( $raq['yith_wcp_component_data'] ) ) {
                                    $component_data                   = $raq['yith_wcp_component_data'];
                                    $composite_stored_data            = $_product->getComponentsData();
                                    $composite_data_price             = 0;
                                    $composite_data_price_with_tax    = 0;
                                    $composite_data_price_without_tax = 0;
                                    foreach ( $composite_stored_data as $wcp_key => $component_item ) {
                                        if ( isset( $component_data['selection_data'][ $wcp_key ] ) && $component_data['selection_data'][ $wcp_key ] > 0 ) {
                                            // variation selected.
                                            if ( isset( $component_data['selection_variation_data'][ $wcp_key ] ) && $component_data['selection_variation_data'][ $wcp_key ] > 0 ) {
                                                $child_product = wc_get_product( $component_data['selection_variation_data'][ $wcp_key ] );
                                            } else {
                                                $child_product = wc_get_product( $component_data['selection_data'][ $wcp_key ] );
                                            }
                                            if ( ! $child_product ) {
                                                continue;
                                            }
                                            $composite_data_price             += wc_get_price_to_display( $child_product, array( 'qty' => $raq['quantity'] ) );
                                            $composite_data_price_with_tax    += wc_get_price_including_tax( $child_product, array( 'qty' => $raq['quantity'] ) );
                                            $composite_data_price_without_tax += wc_get_price_excluding_tax( $child_product, array( 'qty' => $raq['quantity'] ) );
                                        }
                                    }
                                    $total     += floatval( $price + $composite_data_price );
                                    $total_tax += floatval( $composite_data_price_with_tax - $composite_data_price_without_tax );
                                } else {
                                    $price_with_tax    = wc_get_price_including_tax( $_product, array( 'qty' => $raq['quantity'] ) );
                                    $price_without_tax = wc_get_price_excluding_tax( $_product, array( 'qty' => $raq['quantity'] ) );
                                    $total             += floatval( $price );
                                    $total_tax         += floatval( $price_with_tax - $price_without_tax );
                                }


                                $price    = isset( WC()->cart ) ? WC()->cart->get_product_subtotal( $_product, 1 ) : wc_get_price_to_display( $_product, 1 );
                                $price    = apply_filters( 'yith_ywraq_product_price_html', $price, $_product, $raq );
                                $subtotal = isset( WC()->cart ) ? WC()->cart->get_product_subtotal( $_product, $raq['quantity'] ) : wc_get_price_to_display( $_product, array( 'qty' => $raq['quantity'] ) );
                                $subtotal = apply_filters( 'yith_ywraq_product_subtotal_html', $subtotal, $_product, $raq );

                            } else {
                                $price    = wc_price( 0 );
                                $subtotal = wc_price( 0 );
                            }


                            ?>
                            <tr class="<?php echo esc_attr( apply_filters( 'yith_ywraq_item_class', 'cart_item', $raq_content, $key ) ); ?>" <?php echo esc_attr( apply_filters( 'yith_ywraq_item_attributes', '', $raq_content, $key ) ); ?>>

                                <td class="product-remove">
                                    <?php
                                    echo apply_filters( 'yith_ywraq_item_remove_link', sprintf( '<a href="#"  data-remove-item="%s" data-wp_nonce="%s"  data-product_id="%d" class="yith-ywraq-item-remove remove" title="%s">&times;</a>', esc_attr( $key ), esc_attr( wp_create_nonce( 'remove-request-quote-' . $product_id ) ), esc_attr( $product_id ), esc_attr__( 'Remove this item', 'yith-woocommerce-request-a-quote' ) ), $key ); // phpcs:ignore WordPress.Security.EscapeOutput.OutputNotEscaped
                                    ?>
                                </td>
                                <?php if ( $show_thumbnail ) : ?>
                                    <td class="product-thumbnail">
                                        <?php
                                        /**
                                         * APPLY_FILTERS:ywraq_product_image
                                         *
                                         * Filter the image of product.
                                         *
                                         * @param   string  $product_image  Product image.
                                         * @param   array   $raq            Quote request content.
                                         *
                                         * @return array
                                         */
                                        $thumbnail = apply_filters( 'ywraq_product_image', $_product->get_image(), $raq );

                                        if ( ! $_product->is_visible() || ! apply_filters( 'ywraq_list_show_product_permalinks', true, 'quote-view' ) ) {
                                            echo $thumbnail; // phpcs:ignore WordPress.Security.EscapeOutput.OutputNotEscaped
                                        } else {
                                            printf( '<a href="%s">%s</a>', esc_url( $_product->get_permalink() ), $thumbnail ); // phpcs:ignore WordPress.Security.EscapeOutput.OutputNotEscaped
                                        }
                                        ?>
                                    </td>
                                <?php endif; ?>

                                <td class="product-name"
                                    data-title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Product', 'yith-woocommerce-request-a-quote' ); ?>">
                                    <?php
                                    $title = $_product->get_title(); //phpcs:ignore

                                    if ( '' !== $_product->get_sku() && $show_sku ) {
                                        $sku_label = apply_filters( 'ywraq_sku_label', __( ' SKU:', 'yith-woocommerce-request-a-quote' ) );
                                        $sku       = sprintf( '<br><small>%s %s</small>', $sku_label, $_product->get_sku() );
                                        $title     .= apply_filters( 'ywraq_sku_label_html', $sku, $_product ); //phpcs:ignore
                                    }

                                    if ( ! $_product->is_visible() || ! apply_filters( 'ywraq_list_show_product_permalinks', true, 'quote-view' ) ) :
                                        ?>
                                        <?php echo wp_kses_post( apply_filters( 'ywraq_quote_item_name', $title, $raq, $key ) ); ?>
                                    <?php else : ?>
                                        <a href="<?php echo esc_url( $_product->get_permalink() ); ?>"><?php echo wp_kses_post( apply_filters( 'ywraq_quote_item_name', $title, $raq, $key ) ); ?></a>
                                    <?php endif ?>

                                    <?php
                                    // Meta data.
                                    $item_data = array();

                                    // Variation data.
                                    if ( ! empty( $raq['variation_id'] ) && is_array( $raq['variations'] ) ) {

                                        foreach ( $raq['variations'] as $name => $value ) {
                                            $label = '';

                                            if ( '' === $value || is_a( $value, 'WC_Product_Attribute' ) ) {
                                                continue;
                                            }

                                            $taxonomy = wc_attribute_taxonomy_name( str_replace( 'attribute_pa_', '', urldecode( $name ) ) ); //phpcs:ignore

                                            // If this is a term slug, get the term's nice name.
                                            if ( taxonomy_exists( $taxonomy ) ) {
                                                $term = get_term_by( 'slug', $value, $taxonomy ); //phpcs:ignore
                                                if ( ! is_wp_error( $term ) && $term && $term->name ) {
                                                    $value = $term->name;
                                                }
                                                $label = wc_attribute_label( $taxonomy );

                                            } else {

                                                if ( strpos( $name, 'attribute_' ) !== false ) {
                                                    $custom_att = str_replace( 'attribute_', '', $name );

                                                    if ( '' !== $custom_att ) {
                                                        $label = wc_attribute_label( $custom_att, $_product );
                                                    } else {
                                                        $label = $name;
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }

                                            $item_data[] = array(
                                                'key'   => $label,
                                                'value' => $value,
                                            );
                                        }
                                    }

                                    $item_data = apply_filters( 'ywraq_request_quote_view_item_data', $item_data, $raq, $_product, $show_price );


                                    // Output flat or in list format.
                                    if ( count( $item_data ) > 0 ) {
                                        echo '<br><ul style="margin-left: 10px;">';
                                        foreach ( $item_data as $data ) {
                                            echo '<li><strong>' . esc_html( $data['key'] ) . '</strong>: ' . wp_kses_post( $data['value'] ) . '</li><br>';
                                        }
                                        echo '</ul>';
                                    }

                                    ?>
                                    <?php if ( $show_line_total || $show_single_price ) : ?>
                                        <span class="mobile-price">
                                            <?php
                                            $mobile_price = ( $show_single_price ? $price : $subtotal );
                                            echo wp_kses_post( apply_filters( 'yith_ywraq_hide_price_template', $mobile_price, $product_id, $raq ) );
                                            ?>
                                            </span>

                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                </td>

                                <?php if ( $show_single_price ) : ?>
                                    <td class="product-price"
                                        data-title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Price', 'yith-woocommerce-request-a-quote' ); ?>">
                                        <?php
                                        echo wp_kses_post( apply_filters( 'yith_ywraq_hide_price_template', $price, $product_id, $raq ) );
                                        ?>
                                    </td>
                                <?php endif; ?>

                                <?php if ( $show_quantity ) : ?>
                                    <td class="product-quantity"
                                        data-title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Quantity', 'yith-woocommerce-request-a-quote' ); ?>">
                                        <?php

                                        if ( $_product->is_sold_individually() ) {
                                            $product_quantity = sprintf( '1 <input type="hidden" name="raq[%s][qty]" value="1" />', $key );
                                        } else {

                                            $product_quantity = woocommerce_quantity_input(
                                                array(
                                                    'input_name'  => "raq[{$key}][qty]",
                                                    'input_value' => apply_filters( 'ywraq_quantity_input_value', $raq['quantity'] ),
                                                    'max_value'   => apply_filters( 'ywraq_quantity_max_value', $_product->backorders_allowed() ? '' : $_product->get_stock_quantity(), $_product ),
                                                    'min_value'   => apply_filters( 'ywraq_quantity_min_value', 0, $_product ),
                                                    'step'        => apply_filters( 'ywraq_quantity_step_value', 1, $_product ),
                                                ),
                                                $_product,
                                                false
                                            );
                      // Display Custom Unit
                                        }
                                        echo $product_quantity; //@phpcs:ignore
                                        ?>
                                    </td>
                                <?php endif; ?>

                <!-- Display Product Unit(s) -->
                  <?php
                    if (get_field('units', $product_id, $raq)) :
                      echo get_field('units');
                    endif 
                  ?>

                                <?php if ( $show_line_total ) : ?>
                                    <td class="product-subtotal"
                                        data-title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Price', 'yith-woocommerce-request-a-quote' ); ?>">
                                        <?php echo wp_kses_post( apply_filters( 'yith_ywraq_hide_price_template', $subtotal, $product_id, $raq ) ); ?>
                                    </td>
                                <?php endif ?>
                            </tr>
                        <?php endif; ?>

                        <?php do_action( 'ywraq_after_request_quote_view_item', $raq_content, $key ); ?>

                    <?php endforeach ?>
                    <?php if ( $show_totals ) : ?>
                        <?php
                        if ( $total_tax > 0 && 'incl' !== $tax_display_list && ywraq_show_taxes_on_quote_list() ) :
                            $total += $total_tax;
                            ?>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="raq-totals-row" colspan="<?php echo esc_attr( $colspan ); ?>"
                                    data-colspan-mobile="<?php echo esc_attr( $mobile_colspan ); ?>"></td>
                                <th class="raq-totals-label">
                                    <?php echo esc_html( WC()->countries->tax_or_vat() ); ?>
                                </th>
                                <td class="raq-totals">
                                    <?php echo wp_kses_post( wc_price( $total_tax ) ); ?>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        <tr>
                            <th colspan="<?php echo esc_attr( $colspan ); ?>"
                                data-colspan-mobile="<?php echo esc_attr( $mobile_colspan ); ?>"
                                data-colspan="<?php echo esc_attr( $colspan ); ?>"
                                class="raq-totals-row"></th>
                            <th class="raq-totals-label">
                                <?php esc_html_e( 'Total:', 'yith-woocommerce-request-a-quote' ); ?>
                            </th>
                            <td class="raq-totals"
                                data-title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Total', 'yith-woocommerce-request-a-quote' ); ?>">
                                <?php
                                echo wp_kses_post( wc_price( $total ) );
                                if ( $total_tax > 0 && 'incl' === $tax_display_list && ywraq_show_taxes_on_quote_list() ) {
                                    echo wp_kses_post( '<br><small class="includes_tax">' . sprintf( '%1$s %2$s %3$s', __( 'includes', 'yith-woocommerce-request-a-quote' ), wp_kses_post( wc_price( $total_tax ) ), wp_kses_post( WC()->countries->tax_or_vat() ) ) . '</small>' );
                                }
                                ?>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    <?php endif; ?>

                    </tbody>
        </table>



                <?php
                $show_pdf_button         = get_option( 'ywraq_show_download_pdf_on_request', 'no' ) === 'yes';
                $show_clear_list         = get_option( 'ywraq_show_clear_list_button', 'yes' ) === 'yes';
                $style                   = $show_clear_list || $show_pdf_button ? 'justify-content:space-between' : 'justify-content:end';
                $show_update_list_button = get_option( 'ywraq_show_update_list', 'yes' ) === 'yes';


                if ( $show_pdf_button || $show_update_list_button || $show_clear_list ) : ?>
                    <div class="update-list-wrapper" style="<?php echo esc_attr( $style ); ?>">
                        <div class="after-table-right">
                            <?php if ( $show_clear_list ): ?>
                                <?php $clear_list_btn_label = get_option( 'ywraq_clear_list_label', esc_html__( 'Clear List', 'yith-woocommerce-request-a-quote' ) ); ?>
                                <button class="button ywraq_clean_list"> <?php echo apply_filters( 'ywraq_clear_list_label', $clear_list_btn_label ); ?> </button>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                            <?php if ( $show_pdf_button ): ?>
                                <button id="ywraq-list-to-pdf" class="button button-ghost" data-nonce="<?php echo esc_attr( wp_create_nonce( 'ywraq-list-to-pdf' ) ); ?>">
                                    <?php echo esc_html( get_option( 'ywraq_show_download_pdf_on_request_label', _x( 'PDF', 'Admin option label for button to make a PDF on Request a quote page', 'yith-woocommerce-request-a-quote' ) ) ); ?></button>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        </div>
                        <?php if ( $show_update_list_button ): ?>
                            <input type="submit" class="button" name="update_raq" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_option( 'ywraq_update_list_label' ) ); ?>">
                            <input type="hidden" id="update_raq_wpnonce" name="update_raq_wpnonce"
                                   value="<?php echo esc_attr( wp_create_nonce( 'update-request-quote-quantity' ) ); ?>">
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </div>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php do_action( 'ywraq_after_list_table' ); ?>
            </form>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

My main question is: How exactly do I modify the YITH plugin to display the variable $unit as previously mentioned?

Ive tried numerous approached to no avail. Maybe I'm writing it wrong, idk. Any guidance would be appreciated!